# How to convolve these two signals?

Tags: filter, signal, math, convolution

I tried to convolve these two signals (top image). I’m not sure if I have done it properly. My partial answer (further below) is wrong.

[image: the problem, the last pic is answer]

[image: This is what I tried.]

Comment: Pencil and paper I get something more like this:$$\frac{k\,A^2\,t^2\left(3\,T-t\right)}{6\,T^2}$$Only for the region where \$0\le t\le T\$, of course. I may be wrong about it, though. I'd need to spend more time to be more certain.

Comment: (I did [find a page just now](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Convolution/CI.html) which appears to allow you to test the special case where \$k=1\$, \$T=1\$, and \$A=1\$ for your situation. It reports a peak of 1/3rd. Same as my equation. It also reports very similar numbers elsewhere. That may be a point in my favor.)

Comment: If no response, then I'm not likely to add an answer. Just FYI.